# What are the international releases and language versions of "Richard Deacon - In Between"?

Tags: production, distribution, subtitles, richard-deacon-in-between

According to the [Amazon page](https://amzn.eu/d/fL0iXpy) of *[Richard Deacon - In Between](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2892012/)*, this movie, produced in Germany, is available in English and German, where specifically the original track is in English and there's a synchronized voice in German available on this DVD.

I would like to know in which other countries except Germany this movie did appear, and then which other synchronized language tracks or subtitles were made available to the foreign public. Specifically, did it appear in China with Chinese synchronized voice or subtitles?

All sorts of references and links are welcome!

Comment: I disagree with the closure reasons I'm seeing here. Merely asking if these other releases EXIST seems on topic to me. Granted any follow-up question as to being able to locate them would likely be off-topic.

Comment: I just want an answer. What's your profit from closing reasonable questions? What kind of community is this? To answer your question, no I didn't realize this. @Joachim

Comment: And I'm not happy with the edits either or deleting my comments.

Comment: I'm sorry for the adversity you've experienced, but this site has its own set of rules. It seems you already took the [Tour], so you should be familiar with some of them. In the [Help] and on the [Meta] page you can find more information about why questions are closed, why comments are deleted, and why posts are edited. It can be difficult to adjust to this platform, but if you inform yourself, you'll see there is a good explanation for at least most of those things. There is also a [Chat], where you can ask anything about this site.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic. I don't understand why it got close votes. As far as I know, while questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) are off-topic here, there is neither a site policy nor a community consensus to ban all questions that involve identifying something about a movie.